# Excel VBA refusing to Activate a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently writing this program that gets information from other workbooks and organizes them in another workbook. I am trying to activate one of the workbooks that information comes from and it is refusing to activate. I have used this exact syntax before and it has worked, so I'm a little confused why the workbook is not activating. I have confirmed the pathing is correct and the file name is correct. Line 2 is where the issue is `"brakes(i)"` and `"shift(k)"` are arrays getting ran through a for loop to retrieve different CSV files, but instead of activating that workbook it reverts back to the workbook the code is written in. I hope this explanation makes sense :P

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fp3
    Worksheets(brakes(i) & shift(k) & "PartsLog").Activate
```

Comment: Q: Why do you you need to activate the book? A book does not have to be active to be manipulated. You can move,, copy, paste, change, and delete objects (workbooks, sheets, ranges, cells) without them being *active*

Comment: Try adding a Workbooks(...) qualifier to the Worksheets above.

Comment: Adding workbooks didn't help and if you have any other way of extracting data from a workbook let me know, because I am stuck.